# MTB Tyre Safe for Wet Roads

Tags: road-bike, tire, off-road

I ride %50 on road, %50 XC. When the roads are wet/rainy the bike dances with me. Thus, i want to change the tyres.

What I want is safe (in especially wet/rainy conditions) drive both on-road and off-road with a protection against puncture. However, I do not want to give all my effort to friction when I'm on the road.

Which properties should I search for?

Comment: We don't normally do a lot of product recommendations here, but I'm sure some people can help you to look for what features to look for in a tire to meet your needs.

Comment: No knobby is going to do well on wet pavement.   What makes it even worse is what you want for mud is the total opposite - wide spaced knobs.

Comment: The problem with asking for product recommendations is that they don't last – products come and go and technology evolves. Also, in a world wide forum, what is available in one region may not be available in another. Therefore it is better to ask questions that get at the qualities of products that solve particular problems. You could modify this question to ask how to pick tires that would work well for your type of riding.

Comment: It needs to be noted that what you want for plain wet asphalt is different from what you want for semi-dirty wet asphalt is different from what you want for asphalt with a 1/4" layer of mud is different from what you want for off-road in pure mud.  (And that's only just getting started.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments and warnings. I've just edited the question.

Comment: Could you add some more details about your situation? The tires are you running now, and telling us about your riding conditions (see the comment by @DanielRHicks above) would help.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for a puncture resistant semi slick mountain bike tyre. That's a whole set of compromises, and they're not intercompatible.

For a mountain bike tyre you want big knobbly sections and a thin tyre casing so it flexes easily when you run it at low pressure. But on the road you want high pressure, and for puncture resistance you need a thick casing. The problem with getting both big knobs and a slick tyre is obvious, but that's the most easily solved part - a [semi slick tyre](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=semi%20slick%20bicycle%20tyre) - and there are lots of them available.

[image: semi slick bicycle tyre]

Problem is, off road they don't have as much traction as a proper MTB tyre, and on road they're fine until you lean the bike, at which point they lose traction. I've used these for a while when my commute had an off-road option, but I quickly decided I would ride that to work only when it was dry enough to do it on slick tyres. The semi-slicks worked better than slicks on the gravel, not detectably better in mud (but they did throw more mud up onto me and the bike), and on the road the "lose traction on corners" feature was downright dangerous.

My solution was to buy a second hand mountain bike and use the wheels off that for offroad riding (the bike itself was in very poor condition, so it wasn't worth fixing, but the wheels were ok).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What I understand is that what I want is actually impossible. There are always tradeoffs. If you gain something, you lose another. It seems that the only option is giving up searching for a tire perfect for everything.